# Why i can't use console output in QBS project?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qbs

In my qbs file:

```
import qbs

Project {
    name: {
            console.info("Hello!");
            return "ProjectName";
    }
 ...
 }
```

I've got message: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: console

My Qt version is 5.5.0. My Qt Creator version is 3.5.1

I've use binaries from MSYS2 repo.

**EDIT:** I can see methods of `console` variable in text editor by Ctrl-Space hotkey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [console logging API](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/jsextensions-general.html#console-api) is supported in Qbs 1.5 and its output will show up in Qt Creator's General Messages tab. In Qbs 1.4.5 and below, print() is the only debugging function available. As the other answer shows, you'll have to use that or `throw`.

<strike>A release date for Qbs 1.5 has not yet been set.</strike> Qbs 1.5 was released Wednesday the 11th of May 2016.

Comment: 1.5.0 does. 1.4.5 does not.

Comment: @JakePetroules I just tried QtCreator 4.2.1 and Qbs 1.7.1 on Wiindows and there is still no output from console.log.

Comment: @JakePetroules I figured it out but it is not explained how does one set the warning level? BTW.. I've noticed that qbs supports colorized console output it would be nice if Qbs allows the console logging api to set colors for its output too.

Comment: You can use the --log-level, -v and -vv options to increase the verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure why `console` object isn't supported in *qbs* (still stuck in *qmake* land myself), you can get console output with [`print`](https://wiki.qt.io/Qbs_Quick_Reference#message.28.29.2C_warning.28.29.2C_error.28.29):

```
        print("Hello!");
```

This works in console, but not in Qt Creator, yet. This will be resolved in qbs 1.5, but it isn't released yet at the time of writing this, as pointed out by @JakePetroules. The relevant, resolved bug report is [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QBS-548).

For older versions, it seems you just have to either `throw "Hello!";` (which makes the build fail), or run qbs from command line when debugging the project building (the used command can be conveniently copied from Qt Creator Projects view).

---

As to why Qt Creator autocompletion shows it, it'll hazard a guess: it might because `console` is hard-coded into its Javascript auto-completion as a core Javascript feature which is always available. Might be worth writing [a bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa)!

Comment: Unfortunately, print() function works only in console, not in Qt Creator output.

Comment: Qt Creator 3.6 comes with Qbs 1.4.4.